# How to print current file name with logger?

Tags: python, logging

I am using the Logger model in Python.
I want the log to also print the file name from which the logger is called. 
How could this be done?

This is my current implemation:

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # create the logging file handler
        fh = logging.FileHandler("{}.log".format(name))

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)

        # Add handle to logger object
        self.logger.addHandler(fh)

    def get_logger(self):
        return self.logger
```

Comment: What you trying to do is usually done with `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. This will use the dotted name of the module and create and hierarchical structure in the logging system. [details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects)

Comment: I want it to happen for every file that made log.info. not only the creating one.

Comment: This post is not clear. How do you use your custom Logger in other files? You should provide a self-contained example .

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig()

    LOG.error("Foo")
    LOG.error(__file__)
```

Results in:

```
ERROR:__main__:Foo
ERROR:__main__:mylog.py
```

For something more complex, you can use the logger configuration to set a a log message formatter that uses the `filename` attribute of the `LogRecord`s to include the filename in every log line without making it part of the log message body.

E.g.

```
logging.basicConfig(format="%(filename)s: %(message)s")
```

will result in log lines:

```
mylog.py: Foo
mylog.py: mylog.py
```

Comment: I am using: self.logger = logging.getLogger(name). How do I set the config file? and how do I set it to override the previous log file? See updated question.

Comment: The thing is I'm not using logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to override the previously created log file?

Comment: Have a read through the tutorial doc I linked to, and then probably best to open a new SO question if you still need to